# Scrape data from website to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape weather data from the met office website, but I keep getting errors.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
stats = ['Tmax', 'Tmin', 'Rainfall']
regions = ['England', 'Wales', 'Scotland']
base_url = r'https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/datasets/{}/date/{}.txt'
dframes = []

for r in regions:
    for s in stats:
        url = base_url.format(s,r)
        df = pd.read_table(requests.get(url).content)
        dframes.append(df)
```

I'm gettin an error:

```
"OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type"
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: sorry, I will update

Comment: Put in the line `import pandas as pd` early in the code.

Comment: i cant add the full error message, I think its too big?

Comment: i already have pandas imported @BillBell

Comment: We can't see that, eh.

Comment: At least add the line number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use that bytes through a stream for example `io.BytesIO`:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

stats = ['Tmax', 'Tmin', 'Rainfall']
regions = ['England', 'Wales', 'Scotland']
base_url = r'https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/datasets/{}/date/{}.txt'
dframes = []

for r in regions:
    for s in stats:
        url = base_url.format(s,r)
        df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
        dframes.append(df)
print(dframes)
```